# Cannot return id as json object using php

Tags: php, android

I am creating an android application and I am currently creating groups. Everything is fine when I insert the group into the table and echoing "success" as a JSON object.

The problem is, I need to retrieve the auto incremented id from this group.
This is what my php looks like.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect();

    $gname = $_POST["gname"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO groups (gname) VALUES (?)");
    $id =  mysql_insert_id();
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $gname);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true; 
    $response["id"] = $id;


    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

When I added the lines

```
$id =  mysql_insert_id();
```

and

```
$response["id"] = $id;
```

the program stopped working. How do I retrieve the Id?

Comment: First of all, mysql vs mysqli? second of all, I always thought you need to execute the query first before asking last insert id..

Comment: You cannot mix `mysqli_` and `mysql_` API's change `mysql_insert_id()` to `mysqli_insert_id($con)`

Comment: Remove the line ` $id =  mysql_insert_id();` and replace this line `$response["id"] = $id;` with $response["id"] =  mysqli_insert_id();;

Comment: @AnuranjanPandey Thanks it solved my problem!!